# Disable "Address" fields in Customer Registration Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am using Intenso package.

For registration, under persistent package

By default Country, and address options are removed,

But when I submit Customer registration form,

Magento error comes out as

```
"Street Address" is a required value.
"Street Address" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
"City" is a required value.
"City" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
"Country" is a required value.
"Zip/Postal Code" is a required value.
"Telephone" is a required value.
"Telephone" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
Please enter the street.
Please enter the city.
Please enter the telephone number.
Please enter the zip/postal code.
Please enter the country.
```

How to disable these fields,

also these are not present in my register.phtml, still error is coming

Comment: you get these errors in magento session ? I mean if these errors are displayed after the page is refreshed or you get this error in just after you click submit

Comment: after submission